# Can't compile due to no such module '__ObjC'

Tags: ios, objective-c, flutter, xcode, ios-simulator

I'm trying to build for iOS in flutter.　However, the compilation could not be completed because the module `__ObjC` was not found.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 13 Pro Max in debug mode...
main.dart:1
Xcode build done.                                           42.7s
Failed to build iOS app
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Using bridging headers with module interfaces is unsupported

Uncategorized (Xcode): Command SwiftDriver emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure

Error (Xcode): no such module '__ObjC'
/Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gnvomxdvkbnvhiftqgeatxtbshib/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Runner.private.swiftinterface:11:18

Error (Xcode): failed to verify module interface of 'Runner' due to the errors above; the textual interface may be broken by project issues or a compiler bug
/Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gnvomxdvkbnvhiftqgeatxtbshib/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Runner.private.swiftinterface:0:0

Error (Xcode): no such module '__ObjC'
/Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gnvomxdvkbnvhiftqgeatxtbshib/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Runner.swiftinterface:11:18

Error (Xcode): failed to verify module interface of 'Runner' due to the errors above; the textual interface may be broken by project issues or a compiler bug
/Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gnvomxdvkbnvhiftqgeatxtbshib/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Runner.swiftinterface:0:0

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 13 Pro Max.
Exited
```

What is __ObjC? This happens after upgrading Xcode version to 14.3.
How can this be fixed? Please someone answer.

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.6, on macOS 13.3.1 22E261 darwin-arm64, locale ja-JP)
    • Flutter version 3.7.6 on channel stable at /Users/myname/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 12cb4eb7a0 (6 weeks ago), 2023-03-01 10:29:26 -0800
    • Engine revision ada363ee93
    • Dart version 2.19.3
    • DevTools version 2.20.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/myname/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 32.1.0-rc1
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14E222b
    • CocoaPods version 1.12.0

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.77.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.62.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • iPhone 13 Pro Max (mobile) • 63E17FF6-0922-418E-A209-49173C8A4E71 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-15-4 (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)            • macos                                • darwin-arm64   • macOS 13.3.1 22E261 darwin-arm64
    • Chrome (web)               • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 112.0.5615.49

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am experiencing the same issue here after upgrading xcode to 14.3.

Comment: I solved by downgrading Xcode to 14.2

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did the same for now. Couldn't get it working on Xcode 14.3, sadly.

Comment: Did you remove the old one? Same error code?

Answer (score 1):

Following this topic https://github.com/rafaelsetragni/awesome_notifications/issues/773

I have avoided this issue by comeback to version 0.6.21 of `awesome_notifications`

Answer (score 0):

Following the discussion on [this github issue](https://github.com/rafaelsetragni/awesome_notifications/issues/874), I managed to solve the issue without downgrading the version of `awesome_nofitications`.
It seems that changing the following settings in Xcode will solve the problem:

In Runner Target:

Build libraries for distribution => NO

Only safe API extensions => NO

iOS Deployment Target => 11 or greater

In all other Targets:

Build libraries for distribution => NO

Only safe API extensions => YES

iOS Deployment Target => 11 or greater